# Build templated directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have blocks of HTML like this that repeat tons of time in my code:

```html
<div>
    <label for="producer">Producer:</label>
    <select id="producer" ng-model="producer" ng-options="producer.name for producer in producers">
        <option value="">-- Choose Producer --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

So I want to make a directive (??) where I could instead do this:

```html
<gsBoundSelect gsLabel="Producer:" gsDefaultOption="-- Choose Producer --"
               ng-model="producer" 
               ng-options="producer.name for producer in producers" />
```

The for/id fields could just be a random generated string.

I've been reading up on directives but I can't quite figure out exactly how to do this so that I can pass in parameters like this.  The examples I've seen all want a bound scope variable passed in vs an attribute.

It seems like I need both a link function *and* a template, but I'm confused how to do that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found enough data through various books to get something working.  Not sure if it's the *best* way, but it definitely works:

```js
module.directive('gsBoundSelect', function ($compile) {
    function generateUUID() {
        ...
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var lblId = generateUUID();
            var content = [
                '<div>',
                    '  <label for="' + lblId + '">' + attrs.gsLabel + '</label>',
                    '  <select id="' + lblId + '" ng-model="' + attrs.ngModel + '" ng-options="' + attrs.ngOptions + '">',
                    '    <option value="">-- ' + attrs.gsDefaultOption + ' --</option>',
                '  </select>',
                '</div>'].join('');

            // We need to transform the content into a jqLite object
            var jqLiteElem = angular.element(content);
            $compile(jqLiteElem)(scope);

            element.replaceWith(jqLiteElem);
        }
    };
});
```

As a side-note...I discovered the element directives added must be closed with a full tag, not the shorter syntax like I showed in my example.  So the above works with this HTML:

```html
<gsBoundSelect gsLabel="Producer:" gsDefaultOption="-- Choose Producer --"
           ng-model="producer" 
           ng-options="producer.name for producer in producers">
</gsBoundSelect>
```